# Use regular expression to extract longitude from hidden input

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regular expression in php to extract the longitude and latitude from this html:

```
<input type="hidden" value="53.484561000000" id="latitude" />
<input type="hidden" value="-2.951027000000" id="longitude" />
```

I thought something like this might work:

```
preg_match('/id="latitude"\s*value="([^"]+)"/', $scrapedHTML, $lat);
preg_match('/id="longitude"\s*value="([^"]+)"/', $scrapedHTML, $lon);
```

When I do a var_dump of either $lat or $lon I get array(0) {}

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your source contains `value=` then `id=`. But your regex is looking for `id=` first, then `value=`. Doesn't match.

Comment: Try to parse this with an HTML/XML parser, it is the better tool for the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should switch the two parts of your regex.
Try:

```
 /value=\"([^"]+)\"\s*id=\"latitude\"/
 /value=\"([^"]+)\"\s*id=\"longitude\"/
```